# DLL memory mapping or address space allocation in executable

Tags: dll, linker

Correct me if i am wrong.
Question is related to C++ on Windows Console application.

I created two applications, `abc.exe` and `def.exe`, and a DLL called `Funky.dll`. I kept the DLL at location `C:\Funky.dll`.

There is a global string variable in the DLL e.g. "string Value;"
And Dlls exposed function is using that variable.

Below is the DLL code:

```
#include<header files etc>

string Value;

#ifdef _MANAGED
#pragma managed(push, off)
#endif

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{


    return TRUE;
}

#ifdef _MANAGED
#pragma managed(pop)
#endif

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) string Display(string str, int val)
{

    value=str;
    cout<<"\n************I am in a FunkyDLL************\n";
    cout<<"\n"<<value;
    cout<<"\n"<<val;
    printf("\nAddress Space %u::",&value);



return value;
}
```

Now I am accessing the same DLL from two different applications (i.e. `abc.exe` and `def.exe`) but the location of the DLL is the same, i.e. `c:\Funky.dll`.
I call the Display function in both applications in while loop, e.g. for `abc.exe`:

```
while(1)
{
Display("ABC",10);
}
```

and for `def.exe`:

```
while(1)
{
Display("DEF",10);
}
```

Now the display function printing the different values for different application. But the address of the variable is always the same.

Can someone please explain it or provide the link related to address space of DLL in executables.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library#Memory_management)

Answer (score 1):

Each process using you DLL has its own copy of DLL global and static variables. In order to share data between processes you have to manually apply one of the multiple approaches - most oftenly used are making a shared section in a DLL or via the memory mapped files API.

Read carefully all DLL-related material on MSDN ([starting point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and even better - get a copy of Richter's "Programming aplications for Windows"